Summarize The expression refers to multiple columns. Multiple columns cannot be converted to a scalar value
CumpleRequisitos = 
SUMMARIZE (weatherausarreglao
    , weatherausarreglao[Location]  -- Columna por la cual agrupar (GROUP BY)
    , "Max_Temp", AVERAGE(weatherausarreglao[MaxTemp])
    , "Min_Temp", AVERAGE(weatherausarreglao[MinTemp])  -- Expresiones agregadas
)

This is my code am reading the documentation and i cant find how to fix the problem :c
I tried to make a function in dax which returns a "table" with a group by in location and the other column a AVERAGE of temp

could you please provide some sample data and expected output?

You're writing a measure. A measure cannot return a table. A measure must return a single value. Try creating a calculated table with your code instead.
